# Mongoose - find(): object inside search options is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose Schema that looks like this:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  metadata: {
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

I want to get the list of elements in my **mongodb** database applying a filter, so I have the following object:

```
var searchOptions = { metadata: { isDeleted: false } };
```

that always needs to have that `metadata.isDeleted` value set to `false`, appart from other parameters that will be added later, before executing the query:

```
var objQuery = myModel.find(searchOptions, '-metadata');
```

At first, I had `isDeleted` attribute outside my `metadata` object in the Schema, and

```
var searchOptions = { isDeleted: false };
```

used to work perfectly. But it is since I decided to have `isDeleted` inside my `metadata` object that is not working and can't figure out why...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems pretty likely given your use of elipsis in your schema listing that there are more properties than `isDeleted` under the `metadata` property. So your object should be:

```
var searchOptions = { "metadata.isDeleted": false } };
```

The reason for this is that otherwise the query is looking for a document with "exactly" and "only" the properties named under the `metadata` key:

```
var searchOptions = { metadata: { isDeleted: false } };
```

And when that is not the case, then of course there is no match.

Comment: So, for example... quoting will also be necessary when I want to update an element's `metadata.isDeleted` value (for example when gets deleted)... otherwhise passing `{ metadata: { isDeleted: false } }` will substitute the `metadata` object with that one instead of just setting to `true` the `isDeleted` value... am I right?

Comment: @charliebrownie The main thing is the "dot" `.` to access the path to the property rather than using an explicit object so an update would be `{ "$set": { "metadata.isDeleled": true } }`. Otherwise yes, if you did `{ "$set": { "metadata": { "isDeleted": true } } }` then you would be overwriting all other data under `metadata`.