# How to do nested query within an object in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have the following schema:

[image]

I want to find the record for a particular paymentId. How can I achieve this? I've tried:

```
Schema.find({payment:req.body.paymentObj}).then()
```

But this does not work every time since the order of my payment object fields (paymentId,orderId,signature) is different for various records in the mongoDB.

For some, it is paymentId>orderId>signature but for some it is: paymentId>signature>orderId and if the order does not match with my req.body.paymentObj, it does not give me the record.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Schema.find({payment.paymentId:req.body.paymentObj.paymentId}).then()
```

It does not work but how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: this should work `Schema.find({"payment.paymentId": req.body.paymentObj.paymentId})`

Comment: Oh god, this works. I didn't realize putting it in a string might actually work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good i am voting to close this question, related question is already here [Mongoose - find(): object inside search options is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737223/mongoose-find-object-inside-search-options-is-not-working)